# Mock a Static Method which calls a void method with arguments passed into it

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have getNameLength method where I need to mock the setName method using PowerMockito. How should I mock the input paramaters (sb, input) in setName emthod so I can run my getNameLength test case using the mocked data?

```
public class ExampleClass{ 

  public static int getNameLength(StringBuilder sb ){
      setName(sb, "Test");
      return sb.toString().length();
  }

  public static void setName(StringBuilder sb, String input){
      sb.append(input);
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you feel the need to use mocks here?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve here - the example seems a little contrived. Try posting more realistic code instead of an `ExampleClass`

Comment: By the way, you can get the length of the string builder using [`StringBuilder#length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#length()) directly, without passing by `toString()` as intermediate step

Comment: Hint: please give some feedback on my answer. If it is helpful, consider accepting; if not - let me know what is missing for you!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need that set  method at all?

```
public static int getNameLength(StringBuilder sb ){
  sb.append(sb, "Test");
  return sb.toString().length();
```

}

does the very same thing that your code does.

And on your actual question: you don't need a mock for such code. You control all the "inputs" (the StringBuilder that goes into the method); and you get a value back.

So you can write down a simple assert like

```
assertThat(getNameLength(new StringBuilder()), is(4));
```

for example (which checks that adding "Test" to an empty builder results in a 4-char string).

Finally: your problem seems also: you don't understand some basic things about java, and especially **static** it seams. Your example code simply doesn't make sense in the first place. Thus: forget about mocking for the moment; better focus on better understanding what your code should do in the first place!